# Login Status update in php

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Actually, I would like to do when a user is logged in and using their dashboard and i (super admin) update his login status off then his (user) is log out automatically.

Comment: Please provider your actual code...

Answer (score 0):

If you handled the login by creating session, then you can find the session name of that user and destroy it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `enabling` / `disabling` to user is better than removing session.

So that they know, they have been disabled and then contact to admin. otherwise it is weird to remove session without knowing users.

**Don't put the user in dark**

To make this you just need one column  `is_enabled` in `users` table and give all access to only `enabled` user and have facility in super admin side to change this.